# Bezier curve geometry selecting same object - Creating 2 different pipe sizes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry

Would be so grateful if someone can help me here.

I am trying to create a pipes along bezier curves, and eventually (after i get over this hurdle) create different thicknesses along the pipes. But when I create the initial pipes, my bezier curves, are creating completely different sized pipes to start with.

How I did it:

1. I created all my bezier curves
2. Went to geometry in the side panel for each individual bezier curve
3. Selected my bezier circle (0.5mm diameter)
4. Watch it become a pipe on my screen

I tried applying all transforms and clearing everything too but not sure why it's not working. Too me a long time to create the bezier curve so hoping there's a fix rather than re-drawing it.

Would love anyone's help! :) Image attached of the 2 pipes created.

Thank you for reading.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? Maybe in Edit mode select all and right click > Set Curve Radius > 1

Comment: @JachymMichal I think this is the right answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks for suggesting. I gave it a try but unfortunately it didn't work :( @moonboots

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/